# How to iterate over three iterable objects at the same time in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to iterate over three lists at the same time and reference them in each iteration of the loop if that makes sense... however I can't find a simple way to do this...

For example

```
let list1 = [1,2,3,4];
let list2 = [2,4,3,1];
let list3 = [6,53,7,3];

for (x, y, z) in list1, list2, list3 {
   //do stuff
}
```

where x would refer to items in list1, y to list2, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669287/how-can-i-zip-more-than-two-iterators

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Rust 1.59 or higher, the following also works (without needing to depend on `itertools`):

```rust
use std::iter::zip;

fn main() {
  let list1 = [1,2,3,4];
  let list2 = [2,4,3,1];
  let list3 = [6,53,7,3];

  for (x, (y, z)) in zip(list1, zip(list2, list3)) {
    println!("{x}, {y}, {z}");
  }
}
```

Comment: There is really nothing special in 1.59's free-function `zip()` - it just makes it more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools::izip`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.izip.html):

```rust
use itertools::izip;

fn main() {
    let list1 = [1,2,3,4];
    let list2 = [2,4,3,1];
    let list3 = [6,53,7,3];

    for (x, y, z) in izip!(list1, list2, list3) {
       println!("{x}, {y}, {z}");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=24b872e000cb0310973289b98d50930e)

Comment: Or `for ((x, y), z) in list1.into_iter().zip(list2).zip(list3)` without `itertools`.